# Which kind of model is better for keyword-set classification?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, nlp, text-mining, text-classification

There exists a similar task that is named text classification.

But I want to find a kind of model that the inputs are keyword set. And the keyword set is not from a sentence.

For example:

```
input ["apple", "pear", "water melon"] --> target class "fruit"
input ["tomato", "potato"] --> target class "vegetable"
```

Another example:

```
input ["apple", "Peking", "in summer"]  -->  target class "Chinese fruit"
input ["tomato", "New York", "in winter"]  -->  target class "American vegetable"
input ["apple", "Peking", "in winter"]  -->  target class "Chinese fruit"
input ["tomato", "Peking", "in winter"]  -->  target class "Chinese vegetable"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the segment embedding (idea from BERT) for the origin text classification model.

For example:

```
input ["apple", "Peking", "in summer"]  += segment emb [1,2,3,3,0]
input ["tomato", "New York", "in winter"] += segment emb [1,2,2,3,3]
```

where `1,2,3` are something like the data source type for input.

Another improvement: check out PCNN or PCNN+ATT

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00825

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage **word-vector similarity** in [embedding models](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-word-embedding-and-word2vec-652d0c2060fa).

**TL;DR** similiar vectors of words (for example fruits) will be clustered together in this high (vector) dimensional space. For every possible class-set you will have a class-set representative (centroid) that is actually a key (so in your case fruit, vegetable etc) all you need to do is train/find a representative word embedding model of your corpus.